# infinite product of $Z$ hasn't a basis

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups

I was reading [this brief article](http://reh.math.uni-duesseldorf.de/~schroeer/publications_pdf/infinite_product-1.pdf) (I don't know if I am allowed to post links, if don't I apologize) concerning the fact that $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{Z}$ has no basis and is not a free group. The problem is just before the end of the article. When he says that the last equation has solutions for $n=n_1,n_2, \dots$, shouldn't he stop at $n_i$? Then how can he conclude using the final lemma, if we have only a finite number of integers that allow a solution? (that is exacly what the lemma is saying, and so I shouldn't get an absurd).
Probably I am getting something wrong, but I can't figure out where my mistake is. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y=(n_1,n_2,\ldots)$ with $\frac{n_{i+1}}{n_i}\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{\pm 1\}$. Let $i\geq 1$. To get a solution for $\overline{y} = n_i\cdot x \in G/H$, we use the equation $y\equiv (\underbrace{0,\ldots,0}_{i\text{ entries}},n_{i+1},n_{i+2},\ldots)\mod H$. (Note that $\bigoplus_{i=1}^\infty\mathbb{Z}\subset H$) We set 
$$x' =\Big(\underbrace{0,\ldots,0}_{i\text{ entries}},\frac{n_{i+1}}{n_i},\frac{n_{i+2}}{n_i},\ldots\Big)$$
By definition of $y$, the fractions in $x'$ are all integers, i.e. $x'\in G$. So by setting $x = \overline{x'}$, the equation $\overline{y}=n_i\cdot x\in G/H$ is satisfied. This construction can be done for all $i$.

Comment: thanks I think I get it now. What I was not thinking about was the fact that the $y$ he showed was meant to be the solution of the equation for $n=n_i$.

Answer (score 0):

The proof needs infinitely many integers, and we have them: namely all $n_i$.
To get a solution for $ y =n_i \cdot x$ we use the $y$ as constructed there. We can do this for all $i$, so $ y = nx $ has a solution for all $n = n_i$ and this gives a contradiction from the final lemma.

Comment: I don't see it, couldn't you please give an example? I mean, the solution is fixed and I have to find $x$ in $G/H$ given $n$, how are these $x$'s like?

Comment: In fact, $H$ should have elements written with a finite (yet arbitrarely large) number of elements picked from its base.  So that means that $i$ should be fixed given $y$, and that it is finite for every $y$ of that form, but it can be chosen arbitrarely large. Is that so, or ther are actually an infinite number of solution, once chosen $y$?